# NFS Server - Corosync, DRBD & Pacemaker

Tags: ubuntu, pacemaker, drbd, corosync

I have 2 HA NFS server (Ubuntu with CoroSync, Pacemaker & DRBD).

Everything is working beautifully with one small issue.

If I kill an NFS it fails over seamlessly (NICE!)

As the killed node is coming back up it causes a 5-10 second disconnection of the NFS share (presumably as its re-joining the cluster)

Anyone seen this? / any ideas on how to resolve it so that the experience is seamless as it rejoins the cluster.

Comment: You need to check the pacemaker documentation about stickiness

Comment: there is a default resource stickiness that _should_ be enough to keep things from failing back if all other things are in good shape. It sounds like you might be seeing a resource recovery... maybe you forgot to disable some cluster controlled services from starting at boot.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting "wait_for_leasetime_on_stop" to "true".

Answer (score -1):

That sounds like Pacemaker is performing a recovery, possibly after finding the service is running on both nodes after the killed node rejoins.

If you see a message in `/var/log/syslog` from the `pengine` process mentioning something like, "active on 2 nodes attempting recovery", you should make sure you've disabled the `nfs-server` via systemd on both nodes:

```
systemctl disable nfs-server
```

Be sure to check the logs on both nodes.